# checking the validity of a string expression according to some rules

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have this tricky problem that I couldn't solve :

we have a string that contains either "{}" or "[]" sequences, I want to write a function or method that checks if a string is valid: It should retrun true :

- if a string is empty
- if E is valid (containing only the sequences above) then {E} or [E] is valid too.
- or if E and F are concatenantion of valid expressions, the result is also valid.

  ```
  "[{}]" // valid
  "{[}]" // invalid
  "{{[[]]}}" // valid
  "{{[[]]}}{{[[]]}}" // valid
  ```

I tried to solve that problem by scanning the string char by char, I didn't find the suitable algorithm then I thought about regex_match, and finally I said to myself that this kind of problem should be solved with a state machine (like EBNF).

What can you do to solve that problem ?

Comment: just use `std::stack`

Comment: This a traditional "introduction to the stack data structure" problem.

Comment: Just by simple googling [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)

Comment: I can check the equality of the first char and the last "n" then the  second and "n-1" etc... that should fix the second point but it won't work for concatenated strings.

Comment: @Aminos: As in, you have source code for that? Would be useful to edit it into your question, as it can be a building block.

Comment: @AnandUndavia Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you all, I ll answer my question after studying the link Anand gave me. Have a good day.

Comment: Hint: use a stack, when encountering a opening push it, when encountering a closing pop element on the stack and verify correspondance, at the end you should have read everything and the stack should be empty.

Comment: @PaulHankin I took a code from the question you gave me and I converted it to C++. Thank you.

Comment: To the anonymous who downvoted, can you explain why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer in C++

```
   static bool check(const string& sequence)
   {
      if (sequence.empty())
         return true;

      std::stack<char> stack;

      for (size_t i = 0; i < sequence.length(); ++i)
      {
         const char current = sequence.at(i);
         if (current == '{' || current == '[')
            stack.push(current);

         if (current == '}' || current == ']')
         {
            if (stack.empty())
               return false;

            char last = stack.top();
            if (current == '}' && last == '{' || current == ']' && last == '[')
               stack.pop();
            else
               return false;
         }
      }

      return stack.empty();
   }
```